# commands after getting ATR from smart card

Tags: c, apdu, stm32f1

I am working with stm32f103 and st8024 as reader to communicate with smart card. my problem is after I got ATR, I can`t get the response from

```
HAL_SMARTCARD_Receive(&hsc1 , response1 , sizeof(response1) , 1000);
```

above function always returns TIMEOUT for any command. and nothing is put in response1.

below is my code :

```
uint8_t command1[] = {0xC0 , 0x20 , 0 , 1 , 8 , 0x30 , 0x30 , 0x30 , 0x30 , 0x30 , 0x30 , 0x30 , 0x30 , 0};
uint8_t response1[20];
HAL_SMARTCARD_Transmit(&hsc1 , command1 , sizeof(command1),1000);
HAL_Delay(100);
HAL_SMARTCARD_Receive(&hsc1 , response1 , sizeof(response1) , 1000);
```

Comment: OK, is any data actually going out to the card?

Comment: That `HAL_Delay()` looks very suspicious, what if the card responds within 100 ms? Which seems likely?

Comment: @MartinJames 
HAL_Delay() is because of processing time of smart card.

Comment: Re: the delay, as highlighted by @unwind - why?  Will not the receive call just block until data becomes available and, if delayed, maybe cause input overrun?